# SpringBoot - Charts in Web Application

Tags: charts, spring-boot

I am using SpringBoot for my Web Application and I am trying to integrate some charts in one of my pages. I was wondering if anyone could help me or link me a tutorial of how to set the data properly in the javascript function which creates the chart.

I'm using CanvasJS charts and the javascript function to create the chart looks like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
{
  title:{
    text: "Gaming Consoles Sold in 2012"
  },
   data: [
  {
     type: "pie",
   showInLegend: true,
   dataPoints: [
   {  y: 4181563, legendText:"PS 3", indexLabel: "PlayStation 3" },
   {  y: 2175498, legendText:"Wii", indexLabel: "Wii" },
   {  y: 3125844, legendText:"Xbox", indexLabel: "Xbox 360" },
   {  y: 1176121, legendText:"DS" , indexLabel: "Nintendo DS"},
   {  y: 1727161, legendText:"PSP", indexLabel: "PSP" },
   {  y: 4303364, legendText:"3DS" , indexLabel: "Nintendo 3DS"},
   {  y: 1717786, legendText:"Vita" , indexLabel: "PS Vita"}
   ]
 }
 ]
});

chart.render();
}
</script>
```

And the HTML page where I intend to display the charts looks like

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
  <head>
    <title th:text="#{titulo.app}"></title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.scrolly.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.dropotron.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.scrollex.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/skel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/skel-layers.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/init.js"></script>
    <script src="js/funciones.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jcanvasjs.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>


    <div class="12u" th:each="valor : ${listValores}">
        </div>



</body>
```

And 'valor' got a method which returns a HashMap with the data

```
public Map<String,Long> returnData()
```

the String is the indexLabel and the Long is the y value.

How can I pass this Map to the javascript function?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You should convert your Map to a javascript array...which can act as a Map